# FIWARE: IOTAgent JSON add new atrtibute to existing device

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have registered some devices at IOTAgent and Orion Context Broker.

Is it possible to add a new attribute in the registered device at IOTAgent and also at Context Broker ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
POST /v2/entities (if the entity does not already exist) or POST /v2/entities/<id>/attrs?options=append (if the entity already exists).
```

Otherwise have a look the lastest manual, specifically the **appendStrict** and **append** section: [Update action type](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/update_action_types/index.html)